# Having issues integrating jsPlumb with my slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I am using the minimalistic `dragdealer.js` library to create a slider that looks like the following:

[image]

The red blobs have the ids `#drag-button`, `#drag-button2` and so on.

When I try to connect the first two red buttons so that they are adjoined using the following code:

```
        jsPlumb.ready(function() {

            jsPlumb.connect({ source:"drag-button", target: "drag-button2",
                                  paintStyle:{ lineWidth:4, strokeStyle:'rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)' },
                                    anchors:["Center", "Center"],
                                    connector:"Straight",
                                    endpoint:[ "Rectangle", { width:1, height:1 }]
                            });
            jsPlumb.draggable("drag-button");
            jsPlumb.draggable("drag-button2");
        });
```

The first two buttons do not join. **I am however** able to drag a line from the source, but is not even able to join with the other drag-button since it seems to have a different z-index even though I changed this. Here's what I'm talking about, and there's the CSS Code under it: 
[image]

```
#drag-button1{z-index:99;}
#drag-button2{z-index:99;}
#drag-button3{z-index:99;}
._jsPlumb_hover{z-index:99;}
```

I tried making a JSFiddle but was unsuccessful since it did not recognize jsPlumb even though it was pasted in the Javascript portion of it. Can be used to refer to the DOM [still](http://jsfiddle.net/tCk7m/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsPlumb and the Dragdealer plugin don't seem to go well with each other.

The good news is that the discussed slider functionality is easily rebuildable with plain jQuery, thus you don't really need the Dragdealer libraries.

The following jsPlumb/jQuery code, combined with a little tweak in CSS, comes pretty close to the functionality you want, I guess:

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {

  var showRatio = function(left) {
    var maxl = $(this).parent().width() - $(this).width();
    var ratio = Math.round(left / maxl * 100) / 100;
    $(this).children().text(ratio);
  };
  // the following 10 lines just set the initial values:
  var maxWidth = $(".dragdealer").width() -  $(".handle").width();
  var left = 0.3 * maxWidth;
  $("#my-slider .handle").css({left: left});
  showRatio.call($("#my-slider .handle")[0], left);
  left = 0.4 * maxWidth;
  $("#my-slider2 .handle").css({left: left});
  showRatio.call($("#my-slider2 .handle")[0], left);
  left = 0.7 * maxWidth;
  $("#my-slider3 .handle").css({left: left});
  showRatio.call($("#my-slider3 .handle")[0], left);

  // jsPlumb connections and dragging:
  jsPlumb.connect({ 
    source: $("#my-slider .handle"),
    target: $("#my-slider2 .handle"),
    connector:["Bezier", { curviness:70 }],
    cssClass:"c1",
    endpoint:"Blank",
    anchors:["BottomCenter", "TopCenter"],
    paintStyle:{ lineWidth:4, strokeStyle:'rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)' }
  });
  jsPlumb.connect({ 
    source: $("#my-slider2 .handle"),
    target: $("#my-slider3 .handle"),
    connector:["Bezier", { curviness:70 }],
    cssClass:"c1",
    endpoint:"Blank",
    anchors:["BottomCenter", "TopCenter"],
    paintStyle:{ lineWidth:4, strokeStyle:'rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.5)' }
  });

  var dragOptions = {
    axis: "x",
    containment: "parent",
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
      var left = ui.position.left;
      showRatio.call(this, left);
    }
  };
  jsPlumb.draggable($("#my-slider .handle"), dragOptions);
  jsPlumb.draggable($("#my-slider2 .handle"), dragOptions);
  jsPlumb.draggable($("#my-slider3 .handle"), dragOptions);
});
```

Here is a [jsbin fiddle that I've created](http://jsbin.com/uwEYOYa/8/)

Answer (score 2):

I've made you a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tCk7m/5/

Import jQuery via the frameworks & extensions and add recourses via external recourses. I linked to jsplumb 1.5.1 as in the examples on the jsplumb website. I placed your initializing code below all the rest, to prevent errors for object initiazation for classes that don't yet exists.

To fix your z-index problem, you should have used

```
._jsPlumb_connector { z-index:100; }
```

as per http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/styling-via-css

I've also added the firebug thing for easy debug. 
I'm not sure what you're trying to achive. But now you can draw a line (down) from the first slider.
The line will move with the slider.

Hope that helps. If you want a more cleaner jsFiddle, try to move youre library code to a file available on the web.